# How to properly add a value into Vue store and remove it if it's already there?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Let's say we want to add a value to "favorites" in a Vue store:

- If it's already there REMOVE
- Otherwise ADD

I know that the code below is probably neither a correct nor an optimal way of doing it, so I'm wondering what would be a proper way to do it?

### component:

---

`item` is an object, e.g:

```
{ "value": false, "name": "Program Files", "path": "C:\\Program Files", "stat": { "dev": 1990771843, "mode": 16676, "nlink": 1, "uid": 0, "gid": 0, "rdev": 0, "ino": 10133099161787836, "size": 0, "atimeMs": 1520444327295.1216, "mtimeMs": 1520444327295.1216, "ctimeMs": 1520444327295.1216, "birthtimeMs": 1506692793335.212, "atime": "2018-03-07T17:38:47.295Z", "mtime": "2018-03-07T17:38:47.295Z", "ctime": "2018-03-07T17:38:47.295Z", "birthtime": "2017-09-29T13:46:33.335Z" } }
```

---

```html
<v-btn @click="addToFavorites(item)">
  <!-- Displaying needed icon depending on state -->
  <v-icon v-if="inFavorites(item)">fa-bookmark</v-icon>
  <v-icon v-else>far fa-bookmark</v-icon>
</v-btn>

...

computed: {
  inFavorites(item) {
    let favorited = this.$store.state.AppData.favorites.includes(item)
    return favorited ? 'true' : 'false'
  }
},
methods: {
  addToFavorites(item) {
    let favorited = this.$store.state.AppData.favorites.includes(item)
    if (!favorited) {
      this.$store.commit('addToFavorites', item)
    } else {
      this.$store.commit('removeFromFavorites', item)
  }
}
```

### store:

```
const state = {
  favorites: []
}

const mutations = {
  addToFavorites (state, favorites) {
    state.favorites = favorites
  },
  removeFromFavorites (state, favorites) {
    state.favorites.find(favorites).splice(favorites)
  }
}

...
```

Comment: Can you show more details of what is an `item`?

Comment: @acdcjunior sure, I updated the question

Comment: Does this `let favorited = this.$store.state.AppData.favorites.includes(item)` work? I mean, is `favorited` ever `true`?

Comment: @acdcjunior I'm not sure if it's even a correct way to check if it's in there. I'm not very good with JS

Comment: It could be, yes, but only certain conditions. My question was to know if you are meeting such conditions. If so, sometimes it would return `true` indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to find the `item`'s position in the `state.favorites` array, and then remove it by position.

The tricky part is finding the position, but you already seem to have this logic in the `includes` method in:

```
this.$store.state.AppData.favorites.includes(item)
```

So, considering it works, your `removeFromFavorites` mutation would be:

```
  removeFromFavorites (state, item) {
    var itemIndex = state.favorites.indexOf(item);
    state.favorites.splice(itemIndex, 1);
  }
```

## Using a unique property (e.g. `path`) to identify if favorited

Instead of:

```
let favorited = this.$store.state.AppData.favorites.includes(item)
```

Do:

```
let favorited = !!this.$store.state.AppData.favorites.find((i) => i.path === item.path);
```

And, instead of:

```
  removeFromFavorites (state, item) {
    var itemIndex = state.favorites.indexOf(item);
    state.favorites.splice(itemIndex, 1);
  }
```

Do:

```
  removeFromFavorites (state, item) {
    var itemIndex = state.favorites.findIndex((i) => i.path === item.path);
    state.favorites.splice(itemIndex, 1);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me try that

Comment: Though I noticed something strange, maybe you could comment on that? When I store it as an "object" to the store everything works but if I go to other pages (change routes) and come back, it returns `false` when I check the object with `.includes()` again, so it re-saves it again to the array. For some reason it doesn't see it anymore. But if I store items as "strings" instead of objects it can properly find them after I change routes, not sure why that happens.

Comment: Does each favorite has an ID? Maybe that's the fastest/simplest way to handle it

Comment: I mean some unique property, where you can use to compare if two `item`s are the same or not.

Comment: yeah, I think the `item.path` can be used as an `id`, it's unique for every object

Comment: Thank you sir, that works indeed. Though I removed double `not` !! before `this` since it's the same value without it, but yeah, it works perfectly, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with the following code, though I'm not sure if it's the best way, there are surely better ways to do it:

### UPDATED

```
<v-btn @click="addToFavorites(item)">
  <!-- Displaying needed icon depending on state -->
  <v-icon v-if="inFavorites(item)">fa-bookmark</v-icon>
  <v-icon v-else>far fa-bookmark</v-icon>
</v-btn>

...

methods: {
  addToFavorites(item) {
    let favorited = this.$store.state.AppData.favorites.find((i) => i.path === item.path)
    favorited
      ? this.$store.commit('removeFromFavorites', selectedItem)
      : this.$store.commit('addToFavorites', selectedItem)
  },
  inFavorites(item) {
    let favorited = this.$store.state.AppData.favorites.find((i) => i.path === item.path)
    return favorited ? true : false
  }
}
```

### store:

```
const state = {
  favorites: []
}

const mutations = {
  addToFavorites (state, item) {
    state.favorites.push(item)
  },
  removeFromFavorites (state, item) {
    var itemIndex = state.favorites.findIndex((i) => i.path === item.path)
    state.favorites.splice(itemIndex, 1)
  }
}

...
```